# Can you have a Bluetooth Low Energy device connect to an iPhone without an App

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I know you can create Bluetooth Classic devices that can communicate with an iPhone at the OS level (i.e. they appear in the settings tab). Can you do that with a Bluetooth Smart (low energy) only device? Or does iOS require an App to control the Central mode and connect to a particular device? From my understanding iOS requires an App to startup and initiate the CBCentralManager and discover and connect to a peripheral. Curious if there is a way around this without the use of BT Classic.

Answer (score 0):

HealthKit can connect to some specific BLE peripherals (heart rate sensors for example), but in general you need an app to connect to the peripheral.  Without an app a connection doesn't make sense - there is nothing to read and interpret the data from the peripheral.